# Retrieving and updating data from InfoPath repeating tables

Tags: c#, infopath

I've found this [link](https://manojssharepointblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/retrieving-data-from-infopath-repeating-tables/#more-188) helpful in getting data out of field in infopath. Unfortunately, after i attempt to set value back every time users made change on field, it appears to be infinite loop and cause error.

Here is my code:

```
XPathNavigator xNavigation = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator xNodeIterator = xNavigation.Select(“/my:myFields/my:group1/my:group2”, this.NamespaceManager);
while (xNodeIterator.MoveNext()){
  string mystring = xNodeIterator.Current.SelectSingleNode(“my:County”, this.NamespaceManager).Value;
  xNodeIterator.Current.SelectSingleNode(“my:County”, this.NamespaceManager).SetValue("mystring"+ mystring);
}
```

What's the problem here? Please help me.

Comment: As suggested on this page [XPathNavigator.SetValue Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.setvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), you could use the `XPathNavigator` class instead of `XPathNodeIterator` to go through the list. I'll post as an answer my suggested code since there is not enough space here.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, you could use `XPathNavigator` to go through the list without using While loop:

EDITED, based on more info from comments:

```
foreach (XPathNavigator nav in xNavigation.Select(“/my:myFields/my:group1/my:group2”, this.NamespaceManager))
{
    string mystring = myTextBox.Text + ", " + "GUID";  //replace "GUID" with the actual GUID which you need
    nav.SelectSingleNode("my:field3", this.NamespaceManager).SetValue("mystring"+ mystring);
}
```

Basically, you should **not** get the value of the element/node, then set the same element/node's value after adding something to it. That will cause an exponential string expansion.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, but your code still give the same result as the following code(infinite loop). Please help!!

Comment: @KenjiOja Since foreach should ensure no infinite loop (it just goes through the existing elements) could you update your question with the exact error code/message? A screenshot would be very helpful as well.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so late, due to busy weeks. I hope you are still there and willing to help me out on this case. Please refer to the links: [link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AUzi.png), [link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EECI.png), [link3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poQla.png), [link4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qusZc.png),

Comment: I think the problem is that in every loop, we add to the **existing** string inside the node, so it will double the string length every iteration, exponentially. Could you clarify what you mean in your question by "users made change on field"? Are the users changing the XML? Basically we just need to change the line `string mystring = nav.Select...` to get the value *from somewhere else*.

Comment: Let's say, user fills something is textbox, then in onchange event, i want to combine "user input string"+ GUID. Could it be that way ?

Comment: Yes, certainly, is the GUID stored in one of the XML nodes?

Comment: as I quote "Basically, you should not get the value of the element/node, then set the same element/node's value after adding something to it. That will cause an exponential string expansion.", if i want it to be that way, what should i do ?

Comment: If you want to use your method, you will need to disable all other rules on that table, related to that node. Basically I googled your error, and found that there is a "16 actions limitation for each rule without user interaction". If you have a rule updating that table/node, it will run too many times.